# PHP Warning: preg_match()

Tags: php

segue o codigo:

```
$ER = '[\/]?([?]?pag=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(&var1=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var2=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var3=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var4=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?'; // A ER que separa as vars
$wURL = W_URL;
$http = 'http://';
if( $https || $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 80 ){
    $url_site =  str_replace('http:', 'https:', URL_SITE);
}else{
    $url_site =  URL_SITE;
}
$_save_pag = '';
//Executa o rewrite somente quando estiver definido para tal
if($doRewrite == true){

    if(empty($str) && preg_match($ER,$str,$registers)){
```

erro:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?' in /home/sisv2/sis_adm/includes/funcoes/rewrite.func.php on line 17

Comment: Qual é a expressão regular?

Comment: $ER = '[\/]?([?]?pag=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(&var1=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var2=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var3=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var4=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?';

Comment: Complemente a pergunta com a expressão regular.

Comment: pronto coloquei la

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque sua expressão deve ser delimitada por '/' ou '#'.

Logo, ela ficaria assim:

```
$ER = '/[\/]?([?]?pag=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(&var1=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var2=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var3=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?(&var4=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?/'; // A ER que separa as vars
```

Isso acontece porque quando você especifica *opções* para sua expressão regular (multi-linha, linha simples, case sensitive etc.) elas ficam "fora" da expressão, depois do segundo delimitador.